# Is there a way for the concept of life to be evil?

Tags: death, life

I have been formulating this idea where there are two, all-powerful beings that embody the concepts of life and death. For the purpose of this question, I will refer to them as L and D. L and D are extreme with their philosophies. D wants to end all life in the universe while L wants to populate the universe with life. My issue here is L's goal will ultimately result in D's goal; if the population of the universe is left unchecked, overpopulation will ensue and death will be inevitable. Note if D doesn't exist, death doesn't either. Is there any feasible way L or life as a concept can be shown in a bad or evil light, if we ignore the issue i stated above?

Comment: If L doesn't exist, what is D up to?  Did he have some other job?  Without life there is not death.

Comment: [two planets met somewhere at the edge of the universe...](http://www.samuelheller.ch/2007/two-planets/)

Comment: This seems much more of a first-term philosophy question than worldbuilding.

Comment: D has no purpose if L is doesn't exist. Think of them as a simple computer program tasked to do one thing and one thing only

Comment: Hello *Sylvanus*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  While this is an interesting question, it is also very opinion based.  Perhaps you could add some constraints to make it easier to choose one answer over another.  Please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site.  Have a nice day!

Comment: Lots of good answers already.  One point not yet mentioned though:  your L and D are both conscious, intelligent beings.  I.e., they are in fact **alive,** are they not?  So the dispute between L and D isn't so much about life and death in of themselves, but rather *corporeal/biological forms* of life, as opposed to the pure, noncorporeal intelligences that they themselves are.

Comment: @Those saying this is opinion-based:
This question may still be off-topic (a user up above mentioned it appears to be a philosophical question), but I believe it's worth noting the difference between something that has no empirical/science-based answer and something that is opinion-based. Philosophical questions can still receive answers with references or specific expertise. :)

Comment: Quite simply, life is messy and gets in the way of the bookkeeping, so the Auditors try to stamp it out.  Not my idea, Terry Pratchett's.  See "Thief of Time" and "Darwin's Watch", among others.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes - if you populate the universe with life, you speed towards the heat death of the universe.

Take a step back, and take a look at the big picture.

Ignoring the fact that "overpopulation" in and of itself will cause death, the heat death of the universe is the purest form of D's goal. L's goal is simply not sustainable.

Life is basically a complex process through which an organism increases the entropy of the universe. By having more life, you increase the entropy faster, until eventually, you can't, and everything dies, and D is happy.

Comment: So, is life fastening or slowing the "heat death"?

Comment: @Alexander The heat death of the universe is a point in time in where the universe has diminished to a state of no thermodynamic free energy and can no longer sustain processes that increase entropy - thus, life would be shortening the time left before the heat death of the universe comes.

Comment: Not necessarily. On a large timescale, intelligent life would try to conserve as much energy as possible.

Comment: @Alexander The second law of thermodynamics states that the entropy of an isolated system never decreases. Therefore, in the system of the universe, intelligent life can only attempt to slow down their eventual death, and cannot ever stop it.

Comment: My understanding is the stars are the main actors and I'm pretty sure we haven't yet had any observable effect. Type II civilization is required to be relevant. @Alexander Living above 3K (and dropping as the universe expands) is unsustainable, living below that is not currently theoretically possible.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt You're right. But any species that can populate the entire universe is almost guaranteed to be at LEAST type 3 on the kardashev scale (galactic power).

Comment: I highly recommend that you watch this wonderful video that explains why life is the best entropy-generating system https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcfLZSL7YGw

Comment: @Aify so it _can_ attempt (and I think it will).

Comment: @Alexander And i'm saying that even if it does slow it down, it doesn't stop it from eventually dying and achieving D's goal. I don't understand the point of your comment

Comment: @Aify I understand that you suggest that D's goal is to postpone heat death as long as possible. Right?

Comment: @Alexander No, D's goal is "heat death" - the time frame doesn't matter to him, since as long as heat death occurs, D wins.

Comment: @Aify the heat death will occur anyways, unless we allow advanced civilization to beat the laws of physics.

Comment: @Alexander The point is that you can't beat the laws of physics....

Comment: @Aify then Death can just sit back and relax.

Comment: There’s some fun mathematics to show that the creation of organised stuctures that increase entropy is an inevitable consequence of energy moving from place to place. The maths starts with some pretty hard assumptions though, so it’s probably a load of marsh gas.

Answer (score 5):

**All life is suffering.**

[image]
https://blavatskytheosophy.com/desire-the-cause-of-all-suffering/

D feels suffering is evil.  Because suffering is the unavoidable accompaniment of life, life is evil.  D wishes freedom from suffering and the extinction of desire.  L wishes life, desire and suffering.

Answer (score 4):

The living consume resources.

And therein lies your problem. Everything that lives must destroy life in order to live. Were I a god of life and a total enemy of death, I would want to create life that DOESN'T consume resources, at least not in the conventional sense. Even plants need dead things to survive and grow.

What characteristics might that lead to?

- no aging
- no births

No births might seem contrary to the thesis here, which is to propagate life, which is itself a problem, but absolute life would mean that no cells would ever die, making the organism static. Just look at the reproductive cycle--lots of cells have to die for a child to live. Absolute life without death means no progression. It might be peaceful, but it would also be static.

Life eats life. Every carrot, pea, piece of meat and bit of wheat you consume for the energy in your body means the death of those plants and cells.

Look at the first law of thermodynamics. It states that energy cannot be created or destroyed within a closed system. That the energy is simply transferred. When it comes to a living creature, those deaths ARE that transfer, so that continually, the living turn into the dead, transfering energy to the living.

If a god of life is anti-death, then what they object to is the transfer.

Absolute life, therefore, might be stagnation. And that concept can definitely open the door to evil.

As you can see, I am looking at this in a different way than you are. You seem to be ignoring the cycle, and simply looking at loading up more and more life, and saying that it will lead to death because of a lack in resources. But, if your life is consuming, it IS killing. Already leading to death, even as the consumer of that death lives. And the more life there is, the more there will be to consume....but in a closed system there will be a limit to it.

Conceptually, you should probably look at [The Plane of Positive Energy](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Positive_Energy_plane). This is from D&D, and it's an interesting way of looking at life (positive energy) and death (negative energy).

> The Positive Energy plane, sometimes called the Plane of Life or the Positive Material plane...This plane was a continuous explosion of energy not meant for mortals. Despite its nickname the Plane of Life could bring swift death to the unprotected by filling them with positive energy until their cells burst and they joined the conflagration...Both cosmological models were in nearly complete agreement about the nature of this plane, describing it as an infinite, empty, blinding firestorm of life-giving light, but object proof that too much of good thing can kill you—quickly.

Hardly anything can actually live there--and yet, positive energy normally heals.

This isn't scientific, but your question isn't either (and there's nothing wrong with that!) What's important to note here, as in most lore, that evil is all about imbalance. Anything including life itself can be evil if it's unbalanced.

In the World of Darkness RPG, there's a three tiered concept--the Weaver, the Wyld, and the Wyrm. The Wyrm is simply evil, and when it infects the other two, boiler plate, it simply allows them to grow unchecked. (This is the most simple definition, standing back from the game and looking at it). The Weaver represents progress and order, and the Wyld represents raw matter and life/nature.

**Bottom line: Too much of anything is a bad or evil thing.**

Comment: Too much of the Weaver's order is also stasis, probably what D is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In the book "John Dies at The End" A powerful interdimensional nasty is referring to a level of reality that other beings call "Rot-World" where every organism is dedicated to supporting itself off of the consumption and decay of other organisms. He loathes the place and speaks about it like its a madhouse full of predators and scavengers and how everything there is in a desperate struggle to stave off its own decay by consuming the other beings around it. The main charecter asks the being if thats where it came from and it responds that actually its where the main charecter is from, before questioning him as to how he has even managed to stay sane while living in such a disgusting reality. Turns out "Rot-World" is our own reality and beings from other planes of existence regard *US* as the lurching eldritch horrors that need to be eradicated.

Life might be considered evil by an entity from a perspective alien enough from ours that the idea every single meal we eat to stay alive must be made by killing another organism. Life is the process of consumption and multiplication, an endless cycle of killing and devouring in a desperate bid to out-kill and out-devour everything else. Even the passive organisms like plants grow off of the nutrients obtained from the death and decay of other organisms. Even the sunlight that plants photosynthisize with is absorbing the energy from the sun as it slowly dies.

Perhaps Death views Life as an agent of sadistic chaos endlessly perpetuating a cycle of misery and horror (from it's point of view.)

Answer (score 2):

## Life is a mess of destruction

D god loves the perfection, D just want to make an ordered Universe full of schematized stuff. If you have a simple solar system it's quite easy to predict step by step how the system will evolve: how planets will move around the star, how moons will orbit around planets, how the start will deplete its hydrogen and finally make a supernova. All in millions of years.

D thinks about the universe as an agenda or schedule. Nothing is random, he can calculate and predict everything, D loves that.

Instead, **L god is the oppossite**.

L loves chaos, despair and destruction. It's almost completely random the life behaviour. **L want to consume everything**. The ultimate goal of all species is to populate everything and take it. L wants that. L loves to see how its/her/his creatures fights for the scare resources, how creatures harvest, transform and sparse them, scattering all over the world.

How much time do you think it would take for the Sun's expansion to destroy Earth? How much time do you think it would take for humans to deplete and kill Earth?

L just want to get fun seeing the chaos of its/his/her creation, the fights, the depletion of worlds, conquering of galaxies and destruction of suns.

In the end, both of them want the same: life increases the [second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) and the inevitable arrival of the [thermal death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe): [the ultimate fate of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe), which is the true desire of D. The only difference is that L is rushy and wants it quickly, while D isn't rushy and want to see it slowly and contemplate the process in its beauty and perfection.

## L wants death

If everything L creates at the end it ends to die, why L bothers to do it? Well... that is because he enjoys seeing how lives turn in death! L enjoy life suffering and slow degradation. L enjoy watching how life try to avoid its unavoidable end, L enjoys the process. L want to consume everything in inevitable death. L is **the** sadist. Or... maybe... L just fall in love with D, L make living beings in order to be able to kill them for the sake of D fun.

Answer (score 1):

Death is the chance to get things right when life messes up.

Consider the [Aztec Five Suns Creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Suns) myth: it takes the gods a few version of creation before they get things right. Other cultures have creation myths where the current world is not the first one made.

Taking a cue from this, you can portray L as being cruel in creation: creating malformed or pitiful creatures simply because it's *more life*. L doesn't care if a creature is suffering from cancers or if it can no longer support its own weight. Maybe L is not concerned with the *quality* of life, but just in the *quantity* of life.

Answer (score 1):

Universes with life are obnoxious to keep track of.

Without life you can look at a universe every few million years and recompute trajectories of any chaotic events and be pretty sure you aren't missing any details.

Near life everything is chaotic. All of it sorts radioactive isotopes, some of it changes planetary albedo and atmosphere composition, the butterflies are using quantum effects as decorations and then there are the humans. They have the gall to release objects out of their solar system hundreds of millions of years ahead of the expected schedule, introduce new frequency into the spectrum of the system and now are scheming to spread.

It's hard being a good clockmaker with vermin in the mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Life is the fasted way to bring non-catastrophic changes into the world.

If D values some static structures that have unknown properties to living beings, D will be upset when they unwittingly destroy them just to survive. D might consider that life destroys the beauty/perfection of these structures and thus consider it "evil." This may be even truer if this destruction precipitates some catastrophic events.

Possible such structures: patterns in quantum fields, distribution of magical energies (that accumulate in souls), messages written in the fabric of reality (e.g. the operating code, nihilistic poetry, etc.).